# Link isn't appearing on my page

Tags: php, hyperlink, dreamweaver

I'm trying to add a link onto my page with the code below but for some reason it isn't showing up, I've put the area in bold and it all looks correct to me. I presented the whole piece of code as I wasn't sure if it was something to do with the code outside of the bit I have put in bold.

```
<?php session_start();?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Forum</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/source-sans-pro:n6:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <header id="top">
    <h1>ITSize</h1>
    <nav id="mainnav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="Index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Fourth Page.html">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="Second Page.html">Revise</a></li>
        <li><a href="Forum.php">Forum</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <article id="main">
  <br>
  <br>
 <?php 
 include_once("DBconnect.php");
 $cid= $_GET['cid'];

 **if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
     $logged= " | <a href='create_topic.php?cid=".$cid."'>Click here to create a topic</a>";
 }else{
     $logged = " | Please log in to create topics in this forum";**
 }

 $sql = "SELECT id FROM categories WHERE id='".$cid."' LIMIT 1";
 $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 if (mysql_num_rows($res) ==1){
     $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE category_id='".$cid."' ORDER BY topic_reply_date DESC";
     $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
     if (mysql_num_rows($res2)>0){
         $topics .= "<table width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>";
         $topics .= "<tr><td colspan='3'<a href='Forum.php'>Return To Forum</a>".$logged."</td></tr>";
         $topics .= "<tr style='background-colour: #dddddd;'><td>Topic Title</td><td width='65' align='center'>Replies</td><td width='65' align='center'>Views</td</tr>";
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
         $tid = $row['id'];
         $title = $row['topic_title'];
         $views = $row['topic_views'];
         $date = $row['topic_date'];
         $creator =$row['topic_creator'];
         $topics .= "<tr><td><a href='view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid.">".$title."</a><spa class='post_info'>Posted by:".$creator." on ".$date."</span></td><td align='center'>0</td><td align='center'>".$views."</td></tr>";
         $topics .="<tr><td colspan='3'></td></tr>";
         }
     $topics .="</table>";
     }else{
         echo"<p> There are no topics in this category yet</p><br>";
     echo "<a href='Forum.php'>Return To Forum Page</a><br><br>";
     }
 }
 else{
     echo"<p> You are trying to view a category that does not exist</p><br>";
     echo "<a href='Forum.php'>Return To Forum Page</a><br><br>";

 }

 ?>

 </article>
  <aside id="sidebar">


</aside>
  <footer><a href="Third Page.html">My Account</a>
  </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Answer updated .. try this code ..  if worked don't forget to select it as correct answer .

Comment: No its still not working, can you think of any reason why its not working?

Comment: can you show an screenshot of your output ?

Answer (score 1):

after reading whole code :P found some markup errors :) .

in this snippet these all errors are removed ..
now it should work fine .

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Forum</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"; </script>
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/source-sans-pro:n6:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <header id="top">
    <h1>ITSize</h1>
    <nav id="mainnav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="Index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Fourth Page.html">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="Second Page.html">Revise</a></li>
        <li><a href="Forum.php">Forum</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <article id="main">
  <br />
  <br />
<?php 
 require_once("DBconnect.php");
 $cid = $_GET['cid'];

 if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
     $logged = " | <a href='create_topic.php?cid=".$cid."'>Click here to create a topic</a>";
 }else{
     $logged = " | Please log in to create topics in this forum";
 }

 $sql = "SELECT id FROM categories WHERE id='".$cid."' LIMIT 1";
 $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1){
     $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE category_id='".$cid."' ORDER BY topic_reply_date DESC";
     $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
     if (mysql_num_rows($res2)>0){

         $topics  = "<table width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>";
         $topics .= "<tr>
                        <td colspan='3'>
                            <a href='Forum.php'> Return To Forum  </a>".$logged."</td>
                     </tr>";
         $topics .= "<tr style='background-colour: #dddddd;'>
                      <td>Topic Title</td>
                      <td width='65' align='center'>Replies</td>
                      <td width='65' align='center'>Views</td>
                    </tr>";
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res2)){
         $tid     = $row['id'];
         $title   = $row['topic_title'];
         $views   = $row['topic_views'];
         $date    = $row['topic_date'];
         $creator = $row['topic_creator'];
         $topics .= "<tr>
                        <td> <a href='view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid.">".$title."</a>
                             <span class='post_info'>Posted by:".$creator." on ".$date."</span>
                        </td>
                        <td align='center'>0</td>
                        <td align='center'>".$views."</td>
                      </tr>";
         $topics .="<tr>
                        <td colspan='3'>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>";
         }
     $topics     .="</table>";

     echo $topics;

     }else{
         echo"<p> There are no topics in this category yet</p><br>";
     echo "<a href='Forum.php'>Return To Forum Page</a><br><br>";
     }
 }
 else{
     echo"<p> You are trying to view a category that does not exist</p><br>";
     echo "<a href='Forum.php'>Return To Forum Page</a><br><br>";
 }

 ?>

 </article>
  <aside id="sidebar">
  </aside>
  <footer><a href="Third Page.html">My Account</a>
  </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT** 
Code : Updated .

Comment: I tried that and it still hasnt worked the, the only think i need to be output is the link in the first if statement

Comment: can you see the output of `$topics` ?

Comment: No i cant see the output

Comment: No, the link still isnt appearing. have you got any other suggestions? im using this tutorial to make it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0A61f2nofs

Answer (score 0):

You have set the variable $logged to equal your text and then put $logged within the $topics variable and I can't see where you output topics try adding echo $topics to your code

```
<?php 
 include_once("DBconnect.php");
 $cid= $_GET['cid'];

 if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
     $logged= " | <a href='create_topic.php?cid=".$cid."'>Click here to create a topic</a>";
 }else{
     $logged = " | Please log in to create topics in this forum";
 }

 $sql = "SELECT id FROM categories WHERE id='".$cid."' LIMIT 1";
 $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 if (mysql_num_rows($res) ==1){
     $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE category_id='".$cid."' ORDER BY topic_reply_date DESC";
     $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
     if (mysql_num_rows($res2)>0){
         $topics .= "<table width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>";
         $topics .= "<tr><td colspan='3'<a href='Forum.php'>Return To Forum</a>".$logged."</td></tr>";
         $topics .= "<tr style='background-colour: #dddddd;'><td>Topic Title</td><td width='65' align='center'>Replies</td><td width='65' align='center'>Views</td</tr>";
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
         $tid = $row['id'];
         $title = $row['topic_title'];
         $views = $row['topic_views'];
         $date = $row['topic_date'];
         $creator =$row['topic_creator'];
         $topics .= "<tr><td><a href='view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid.">".$title."</a><spa class='post_info'>Posted by:".$creator." on ".$date."</span></td><td align='center'>0</td><td align='center'>".$views."</td></tr>";
         $topics .="<tr><td colspan='3'></td></tr>";
         }
     $topics .="</table>";

     // OUTPUT $topics HERE
     echo $topics;


     }else{
         echo"<p> There are no topics in this category yet</p><br>";
     echo "<a href='Forum.php'>Return To Forum Page</a><br><br>";
     }
 }
 else{
     echo"<p> You are trying to view a category that does not exist</p><br>";
     echo "<a href='Forum.php'>Return To Forum Page</a><br><br>";

 }

 ?>
```

Also, just FYI bolding doesn't seem to work on code.