# Notice: Undefined variable: logged in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\Site\view_category.php

Tags: php

Can anyone explain where my problem is here? im trying to create a link so that the user can go onto create a forum post

```
 include_once("DBconnect.php");
 $cid = $_GET['cid'];

 if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
     $logged .= "  <a href='create_topic.php?cid=".$cid."'>Click here to create a topic</a>";
 }else{
     $logged .= "  Please log in to create topics in this forum";
 }
```

Comment: You are giving the absolute path but should give relative path of file.

Comment: What is unclear about the error messages being presented to you?

Comment: @SumanBogati How would a path have anthing to do with an undefined variable? As far as PHP is concerned, it's simply a string.

Answer (score 2):

#### Initialize the variable before you use it

```
 $logged = ''; //<--- Add here
 if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
```

Since you are using `.=` , it will check whether `$logged` has previously been assigned a value to be appended with your new value.. since there is no such value associated with `$logged` variable , you get that notice.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending to logged but it is not defined try  puttting

```
$logged="";
```

Before the if statement

Answer (score 1):

`$logged .= "…"` is shortcut for `$logged = $logged . "…"`, which includes reading of `$logged`. This causes the mentioned notice if `$logged` is undefined.

Initialize `$logged` with a value before reading it like with an empty string:

```
$logged = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Code to this

```
<?php
include_once("DBconnect.php");
 $cid = $_GET['cid'];
$logged = '';
 if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
     $logged .= "  <a href='create_topic.php?cid=".$cid."'>Click here to create a topic</a>";
 }else{
     $logged .= "  Please log in to create topics in this forum";
 }
?>
```

OR Initialize the variable `$logged` instead of appending value in it .
if `$logged` dose't contain any value before .

```
<?php
include_once("DBconnect.php");
 $cid = $_GET['cid'];
 if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
     $logged = "  <a href='create_topic.php?cid=".$cid."'>Click here to create a topic</a>";
 }else{
     $logged = "  Please log in to create topics in this forum";
 }
// this will print the variable on your page 
 echo $logged;
?>
```

Comment: But why isnt thg link appearing on my page?

Comment: you have to print the `$logged` variable in order to render it . i have added a new line in the answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882209/link-isnt-appearing-on-my-page my full code is there, i dont understand why its not appearing everything seems correct to me

Comment: here is code which will work hopefully 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882209/link-isnt-appearing-on-my-page/22883488#22883488